# Do I include the possessive apostrophe in the parentheses after defining an acronym

Tags: possessives, apostrophe

If I use a possessive apostrophe and then denote a term as an acronym i.e. "the US Government's (USG's)," I don't include the apostrophe after "USG," right? It just feels a bit odd when I don't, as if a term is plural one generally includes the 2nd "s" if denoting an acronym (i.e. Project Managers (PMs).

Comment: I don't think there's a uniquely correct answer to that question. I would include it, or find a work around (by rewording to get rid of the apostrophe, finding another instance of the defined term to host the definition, or including a definitions section).

Comment: The best answer is to avoid defining acronyms in possessive constructions. There is no elegant or even non-terrible way of doing it.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, they are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There's no point in setting up an acronym unless you're going to make multiple uses of it.  So don't feel you have to set it up right at the beginning.  If your first attempt is awkward, and you can't rewrite that part satisfactorily, then wait and set up the acronym a little later (using the full phrase prior to that).  Do make sure you're using it in the singular when you do the set-up.